# Postgres distributing data across multiple disks

Tags: postgresql

I need your help to solve a problem as I am fairly new to Postgres and reading the manuals didn’t help.

We have a server with 4 internal hard disks. We have created a Postgres database with a few tables. We want to be able to spread our data across these 4 disks.

We want to specify somewhere (eg table space creation stage) that the data loaded into a set of tables should be distributed across the 4 disks.

Can you kindly give us the syntax or point us in the right direction?

Comment: Really, why don't just use RAID?

Answer (score 37):

1. Create four tablespaces each one on a different disk (see: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtablespace.html)
2. Move the content of the tables to the tablespaces so that the data is distributed as you intend it to be using `ALTER TABLE foobar SET tablespace = foospace`, see here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altertable.html
3. Move the content of the tables' indexes to the tablespaces using `alter index idx_foo set tablespace = spacefoo`, see here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterindex.html

Comment: so i've done this for one table (78GB on disk).  the new path shows now 78G used, but the disk usage on the original partition remained unchanged.  how do i reclaim the original space?

Comment: turns out a `vacuum` did it.  vacuuming just the one table by itself did not however, very weird.

Comment: Does Commit log file also gets moved ?

Comment: This doesn't help if most of the data is all in the same table, as a table can only use one tablespace.

Answer (score 10):

The best way is to create a RAID-0 or RAID-10 array and let the OS handle this for you.  RAID-0 has no redundancy so any single drive failure is catastrophic.  RAID-10 allows for any one disk to fail and keep right on working with good performance.  Avoid RAID-5 or RAID-6 due to very poor write performance.

Comment: Raid might be a good solution to the problem but it doesn't answer the question. Maybe he wants to have specific data on a specific disk, like put one heavily used table on fast disk and nothing else so the disk is only used by reads and writes to this table.

Comment: Sorry but you're wrong.  The OP stated:

We want to specify somewhere (eg table space creation stage) that the data loaded into a set of tables should be distributed across the 4 disks.

Note that the subjunctive clause in the parenthesis is taken as a kind of guess on how to do it. While it's quite possible to do this with tablespaces and have no redundancy, the better way for 99% of all users is to just put it all on a big RAID array, since then all the tables can benefit from the combined speed plus the redundancy. 

Nit picking doesn't really help.

Comment: RAID5 poor write performance ? Are you doing software RAID ? Hardware RAID works perfectly with RAID 5, you get the best of speed and space. On 4 disks you get the writing speed of 3 of them, whereas in RAID10 you get at most the speed of two.